# Laravel Notification error on MailChannel

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending a notification to a user and getting an error that I can not find much about and have not seen before sending notifications.

```
Trying to get property 'view' of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'view' of non-object at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php:92)


public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $start = Carbon::today()->subDay(1);
        $end = Carbon::today();
        $events = Event::whereBetween('created_at',[$start,$end])
            ->whereNull('eventbrite_id')
            ->count();

        $users = User::whereBetween('created_at',[$start,$end])
            ->count();

        (new MailMessage())
            ->line("Overall stats for ${start} - ${end}")
            ->line("Events: ${events}")
            ->line("Users: ${users}")
            ->subject("stats for ${start} - ${end}");
    }
```

Then when I call the notification inn the job like this

```
$users  = User::where('id',1)->get();
        Notification::send($users,new DailyAdminStats());
```

I get that error. I tried deleting all the carbon dates for the mail message and that did not work so its not anything with carbon. Really confused on what the error is and how to fix it.

Comment: you need to return the mail message object in `toMail` function

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an issue with the code before the (new MailMessage()) line.  I would comment all the code before this and send a dummy message to see if it works.  Then add the lines to identify the error in your code.